# C# Mongo Driver: How to query list of lists?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have two objects

```
public class ParentObject
{
    [BsonId]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<ChildObject> ChildObjects{ get; set; }
}

public class ChildObject
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public string Message{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to write a query that will find `ParentObject` in monogo db with the specific `Id` order all `ChildObjects` that are inside of the `ParentObject` based on `ChildObject.DateTime` and return first 10 `ChildObjects`. How to write it so it runs on the server-side? The important thing is that I want to avoid downloading all child `ChildObjects` to the client.

I wrote this query, but according to the documentation it is run on the client-side which I want to avoid

```
var result = mongoDb.Collection
                .Find(x=> x.Id == request.Id)
                 .Project(x => x.ChildObjects.OrderBy(c => c.DateTime).Take(10))
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

I also tried LINQ but it can not be translated due to unsupported expression tree:

```
            var result = mongoDb.Collection.AsQueryable()
                .Where(x => x.Id== request.Id)
                .Select(x => x.ChildObjects.OrderBy(c => c.DateTime).Take(10))
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

The Error Message: `System.NotSupportedException : The method OrderBy is not supported in the expression tree: {document}{ChildObjects}.OrderBy(c => c.DateTime).`

How to write this query? And how to make sure that it is running on the server-side? Is there a possibility to see the translated query?